# Apache mask on remote server to local server

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, mask

I've setup wiki.example.com (on the remote web server, accessible to the world) to redirect with 301 .htaccess to 192.168.1.x/cgi-bin/foswiki/view (on internal server, accessible only via the LAN).

Is there any way, either on the local or remote, that I can mask the local IP?

So the user would see

```
wiki.example.com
```

in their address bar, and not

```
192.168.1.x/cgi-bin/foswiki/view
```

Both are linux servers running Apache2

In response to the questions below:
@Zoredache - we don't have an internal DNS server, so the fqdn doesn't get reliably resolved.  I might have something wrong in the setup.  You can use netbios names for the windows machines on the network just fine, but the linux machines don't respond 90% of the time.

@Dennis - Below is the current .htaccess on our remote web server

```
redirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ http://192.168.1.x/foswiki 
redirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ http://192.168.1.x/foswiki
```

Maybe I'm not going upon this the right way.  Setting up an internal DNS Server is not an option at this time.

Comment: Why are you redirecting by IP if you don't want the users to see the IP?  It would be helpful to understand a bit more about why you don't simply use the correct fqdn in you redirect.

Comment: Please post your current rewrite rules.

Comment: Did you take the redirectMatch 301 and permanent conditions off when you tried my suggestion?

Comment: yes, I tried it with only your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^/?(.*)  http://192.168.1.x/cgi-bin/foswiki/$1
```

By not using the "[R]" it should leave the URL alone in the browser's address bar.

Comment: I think it will always redirect if you have http[s]:// in the redirect URL.

Comment: That worked to redirect, however, the URL in the address bar does change to reflect the inter 192.168.1.x IP #.
Any other ideas?

Comment: hmm, something must have changed serverside, that worked before, now example.com/wiki takes me to http://192.168.1.x/cgi-bin/foswiki/home/csts/public_html/wiki.  

Looks like something changed on the server side that the $1 variable is getting passed wrong